# TypeError: t.useContext(...) is null error in react router Link (React + Webpack)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

I have a project of react + django + webpack. I defined Routes on my `App.js`

```
<NavBar />
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

I defined `Links` in my `NavBar.js` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

If I used `Link` in `App.js` it works normally but when I use it in the component `NavBar.js` I get this error:

[image]

WebPack config:

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
  }
};
```

I tried using `Switch` as well but it only worked using hyperlinks `<a>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are rendering the `Link` components ***outside*** the routing context provided by `Router` component. Move `NavBar` into the routing context.

```
<Router> // <-- provides routing context
  <NavBar /> // <-- inside routing context
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: Its always the simplest of things... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
call Navbar component in App.js inside the Router component
<div className='App'>
    <Router>
    <Navbar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1>This is the home page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/tutorials" element={<h1>This is the tutorials page</h1>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<h1>This is the about page</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add a description of the code.